# Aborting repartitioning

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

Around 5 days ago I decided to change the partitions on my external HDD. The partitions were full, but there was some space not used by them, so I wanted to move the partitions to the left and expand them. It was supposed to run 17 hours, but now it is still running:

[image]

It says 2 MB/s (thus 170 GB/day), but that seems to have been averaged over the entire time, where it started with almost 40 MB/s. Now it is more like 50 GB / day.

The drive is starting to have issues:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   001   001   051    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 398872
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   172   171   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4366
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       457
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1697
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       444
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       83
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       5460
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   108   102   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   158   158   000    Old_age   Offline      -       17197
```

It did not have such a high FAILING_NOW Raw_Read_Error_Rate before I started gparted

Is it possible to abort the partition changing without losing data? With all these read errors, I am not sure it is actually moving stuff and not just erasing it.

Anyways, it is changing /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3, and it has not touched /dev/sda3, yet. So a safe time to abort it, would be once it has finished with /dev/sda2.

Could I just remove the /dev/sda3 link from the /dev/ directory? If gparted could not find /dev/sda3 anymore, it could not mess with it

Comment: You a drive so full you shouldn't touch the partitions, for starters. And I/O errors typically are a symptom of a failing drive. Hope you have backups.

Comment: what manufacturer made your disk? Seagate uses a very confusing and unorthodox method for recording Raw Read Error Rate and Raw Seek Error Rate, so your SMART utils need to be able to cope with that. that said even then it does look like you have serious issues.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: My backups are on the drive! It is my backup drive. I am not sure what else is there since now I can't really mount it and look at the files

Comment: @FrankThomas: It is a `Western Digital Green Device`,  `Model:WDC WD20EZRX-00D8PB0`

Comment: @BeniBela - We can’t change the fact your drive is starting to fail.  Beyond the fact a simple partition operation is taking to long the S.M.A.R.T data is suggesting it’s also failing

Comment: so, your disk is failing. if you are prepared to pay someone a potentially large amount of money to recover the data, I'd recommend pulling the plug and sending it to your repair folks immediately. in all likelihood, if you did abort the repartitioning, you would probably not have a disk with mountable volumes (due to the partial partition table changes), so you would be left with options like File-Carving utilities for data recovery (though this is far from perfect, especially if no filesystem metadata is available).  but you are fighting to get what you can off it before its final breath.

Comment: You are between a rock and a hard place - aborting the copy will very likely leave the drive in a stuffed state.  It may well not be safe to abort once it has finished with /dev/sda2 if there is any data of value on /dev/sda3 because the partitions alignment wont match the filesystem.    If this is your backup drive, maybe just abort this and initiate a new set of backups on as new drive.

Comment: It made almost no progress with the repartitioning this night. It copied something, but less than 1 GB. However, gparted seems to process one partition after the other. So /dev/sda3 (where the more important files are) is still where it was. So I can mount it and copy the files without issue. Except it is also slow at 0.3 MB / s.

Comment: The problem here is aborting it will corrupt your partition, your just going to have to wait.  Regarding the read errors, the drive doesn't check sectors it doesn't touch so bit rot occurs and you don't know it.  Now that you are basically copying all the sectors in the partition SMART is checking all the sectors in that partition and saying surprise you have a bunch of bit rot I didn't notice before.  The sectors were already weak or bad it just took till now for the drive to notice it.

Comment: @cybernard: I actually did start a SMART long test before starting the partitioning to check all sectors. But it ran into the same problem and got stuck at 90%. Then I aborted it because that test can be aborted without issues. I thought perhaps just the SMART is broken. I also took it as reason to buy a replacement drive last month. But also because the partition was full, and of course I could not copy the files on the replacement drive, because then that one would also be full

Comment: Progress! After being stuck at 77% for several days, it has reached 78%! But at its current speed of exactly 1 block / second, it will have to run continuously for over 2 years. That is getting critical, since I need to get on a transatlantic flight next week. Thus I am now looking into suspending the partitioning. I have discovered that you can pause a process with gdb and override the file descriptors. Using this, I have turned off the drive, exchanged the cable, and turned it on again. That did not help, but /dev/sda2 has become /dev/sdc2.

Comment: But if I use gdb to pause it, I still cannot turn off my laptop. I cannot keep my laptop running on the airplane. 
Now I need something to write a process to disk. 
I tried [criu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24991425/1501222), but it does not seem to support open /dev/ files